# PowerQuery M Conditional Column 'count' argument is out of range

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a sheet with dates as MMDDYYY with no leading 0's if month number is single digit. For example, 1012018 or 12312018. Each record has a date, and each date is either 7 or 8 characters in length.

Here is the code I am using to convert the numbers to dates:

```
if Text.Length([ContractDate]) = 7

then 
Text.Range([ContractDate],0,1)&"/"&Text.Range([ContractDate],1,2)&"/"&Text.Range([ContractDate],4,4) 

else
Text.Range([ContractDate],0,2)&"/"&Text.Range([ContractDate],2,2)&"/"&Text.Range([ContractDate],4,4)
```

The code works fine for the "else" condition but I am getting error "Expression.Error: The 'count' argument is out of range. Details: 4" for all records where Text.Length() = 7. I verified this by adding a second column to get Length of ContractDate.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Problem Solved - I'm an idiot. I was getting an error because in the "then" condition, I am extracting a substring of (4,4) from a value that only has Len=7. I can't get 4 characters out of a 7 character string when starting at index of 4.

Answer (score 3):

I know you found the issue with your code, but worth pointing out some things that might be good to know.

Text.Range with no character count will pull in all characters past the start point (so Text.Range([ContractDate], 4) would work for both).

Text.Middle operates like Text.Range but will not cause an error if you select a range that expands past the size of the string. This can be useful if for some reason you were dealing with variable size strings where you need a specific number of characters up to a limit past a certain position.

You could also use Text.PadStart([ContractDate], 8, "0") to pad the 7 length strings with a 0 at the start, and avoid the need for a conditional check all together.